Connect on-prem SQL Server database to AWS Glue using JDBC
I need to connect a client database, which is a private database only accessible through VDI. I need to connect this database with AWS Glue using JDBC. when I configured JDBC and VPC settings and performed test connections. It shows a connection timeout.
I tried to give the IP and port of that database to the security group of VPC, but it didn't work.
it shows the error

Connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.

As I needed to connect using JDBC, I provided the IP, port, username, and password, which the client provided.
I researched as well, but it shows  set up a VPN. Is it necessary to set up a VPN?

If you are using AWS Glue, you must choose between VPN or AWS Direct Connect, but you must configure the subnet and security group. If you have a firewall, you must configure it to allow the connection as well.
Don't forget the rules related to the instance itself.
Check the logs of AWS Glue for more details !

need vpn even if the database is on cloud but in private data center of client?

instance rules means inbound and outbout rules in sg?

If the client’s database is likely hosted in a private network behind a VDI or within a private subnet. This means that only machines within the private network or VDI environment can access the database. Yes, inbound and oubound rules in sg !  A VPN or VPC Peering !

I created the AWS RDS database (sql server database) and am trying to connect with my local SSMs but am facing an error. I even configured inbound and outbound rules.
error: a network related or instance specific error occured while establishing a connection to the SQL server. The server was not found or was not accessible. (the network path not found.)

"only machines within the private network or VDI environment can access the database."
Yes, they can access it through VDI, but I need to connect that DB to AWS glue using JDBC.

Have you tried to ping it before ?

yes, but didnt work

i gave my ip in inbound and outbound rules as well, give the publicly access set yo yes, but still didnt work

I have find this documentation who can perhaps help you : https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/big-data/how-to-access-and-analyze-on-premises-data-stores-using-aws-glue/

okay, will setup a vpn and connect to aws glue with database
